# How to implement ‘Reverse bidding’ (Reverse auction) in nopcommerce?(providers bid for a specific job posted by customer)

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to ‘Reverse bidding’ option in nopcommerece. E.g I am customer need to service and repair my car. I will create job on nopcommerce portal and add picture of my car. Now, providers will see my job and bid for it. I can see bids and choose the best one.

I have found ‘NOPCOMMERCE AUCTION PLUGIN’ but it does not support reverse bidding.  Is there any other plugins available for this functionality or we need to customize code? In case we need to customize code then please help me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is really *different* requirement then regular we have, that's why not a single plugin is fulfilled your requirement.

> Is there any other plugins available for this functionality

Instead of asking for availability of plugin, I would prefer to search it to 
 the [Marketplace](https://www.nopcommerce.com/marketplace.aspx?searchterm=auction).
If you don't want to make your hand dirty, you can ask plugin vendor to make it for you, they will customize plugin as per your requirement(with some cost *obviously!*)

> or we need to customize code?

You can also choose this option, but there will be a lot of customization needed.

First, you need to give access to the user(s) to upload product(a job in this case) and all other vendors will see that job and bid on it and so on..

Either you can customize order functionality from user side, and all vendors can see that order.

Instead of making manor changes into running code, I would prefer to create your separate plugin and handle all the thing with it, and disable default functionalities which are not required to you.

Hope this helps!